# Printf gets program stuck with no response

Tags: c, printf

This code gets and prints all the window titles and hwnd. However, there is problem with this line of code:

```
printf("----%s\n",hwndTitlePtrCollection[idx-1]);
```

If I delete this line, the app runs OK, else it gets stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t* hwndCollection;
char**    hwndTitlePtrCollection;
uint64_t  idx;
BOOL CALLBACK WindowFoundCB(HWND hwnd, char* param) {
    char *strIn2 = (char*) param;
    char *strIte;
    GetWindowText(hwnd, strIte, 256);
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)){
       idx++;

       hwndCollection = (uint64_t *)realloc(hwndCollection,idx*sizeof(uint64_t));
       hwndCollection[idx-1] =  hwnd;
       printf("**** get a window's number ****\n");
       printf("----%d----%d\n",hwnd,hwndCollection[idx-1]);

       hwndTitlePtrCollection = (char**)realloc(hwndTitlePtrCollection,idx*sizeof(char*));
       hwndTitlePtrCollection[idx-1] = strIte;
       printf("**** get a window's Title ****\n");
       // this line if delete, runs OK. If exist, got stuck here
       printf("----%s\n",hwndTitlePtrCollection[idx-1]);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    idx = 0;
    char* aStr = "good";
    hwndCollection = (uint64_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*1);
    hwndTitlePtrCollection = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*1);
    EnumWindows(WindowFoundCB,&aStr);
    printf("total query recorded is: %d\n",idx);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised the code gets as far as the line you've mentioned - maybe just luck - because you have some major errors elsewhere. These will cause ***undefined behaviour***. See the comments and fixes in the code below:

```
BOOL CALLBACK WindowFoundCB(HWND hwnd, char* param) {
    char *strIn2 = (char*) param;
//  char *strIte; // You are not actually allocating any memory here!
    char strIte[256]; // This way, you have allocated 256 bytes for the Window name.
    GetWindowText(hwnd, strIte, 256); // In the uncorrected version, this is UB!
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)){
        idx++;

        hwndCollection = (uint64_t *)realloc(hwndCollection,idx*sizeof(uint64_t));
        hwndCollection[idx-1] =  hwnd;
        printf("**** get a window's number ****\n");
        printf("----%d----%d\n",hwnd,hwndCollection[idx-1]);

        // EDIT (1a)!
        // The following line allocates pointers to strings, but no memory for the strings...
        hwndTitlePtrCollection = (char**)realloc(hwndTitlePtrCollection,idx*sizeof(char*));
        // Here, we allocate memory for the new string …
        // EDIT (1b)!
        hwndTitlePtrCollection[idx-1] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    //  hwndTitlePtrCollection[idx-1] = strIte; // Wrong! This just copies the pointer...
        strcpy(hwndTitlePtrCollection[idx-1], strIte); // ...this copies the contents.
        printf("**** get a window's Title ****\n");
        // this line if delete, runs OK. If exist, got stuck here
        printf("----%s\n",hwndTitlePtrCollection[idx-1]);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Try this (there may be other errors, too, but let's work our way through)! Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

Comment: Hi,I tried your version and found that this time it does not stuck at beginning, but after print for 3 times, it stuck again. below is the output which is better than my first time:

Comment: Hello world!

**** get a window's number ****
----66594----66594
**** get a window's Title ****
----
**** get a window's number ****
----196738----196738
**** get a window's Title ****
----
**** get a window's number ****
----4790020----4790020

Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 4.928 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: I have paste the output in the answer above.Thanks.

Comment: Got it. Its a tick

Comment: My aim is to make this code as a mex C-code for matlab to use. I still have a problem to make it work. May I post a new question, or edit this question?

Comment: @mendel Probably best as a new question - but you can always reference/link this one, for good measure. (PS: I know very little about `matlab` and even less about "mex C-code!")

Comment: The new post is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258013/mex-c-code-for-matlab-problems-returns-a-list-of-string-back-to-matlab